# iPhone and it's wireless area

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to discover other iPhones in the range of it's wireless area? So I give an example. I am staying at the airport. Somewhere near me there is also an iPhone. Me and the other iPhone's owner playing the same game. Is there a way to alert me and the other player that we are so close to eachother? Is this working also if we aren't on the same wireless networ, or there aren't any wireless?
And if there is a way to do this, can you give me some start point? Like a link where I can learn the basics or something like this. Maybe the name of this procedure, because I either don't know how to search in google about this topic. Thanks in forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The peer-to-peer discovery and connectivity you're describing can be accomplished with Game Kit framework. 
Originally I thought it only worked via bluetooth,  but after quickly looking over this [GameKit Wifi question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821928/gamekit-wifi-connection) it seems wifi is also supported.

Hope this helps!