# Does Bluetooth p2p connectivity work on iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, ipad, gamekit

Does Bluetooth p2p connectivity work on iPhone simulator? I want to test GameKit connection over bluetooth with an iPad but have only one physical device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not.  From the [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1):

> Bluetooth networking is not supported
>   on the original iPhone or the
>   first-generation iPod Touch. It is
>   also not supported in Simulator.

However, as of iPhone OS 3.1 [Game Kit can also use WiFi for peer-to-peer communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821928/gamekit-wifi-connection).  I've read [some reports](http://volcore.limbicsoft.com/2009/09/iphone-os-31-gamekit-pt-1-woooohooo.html) of this working between the Simulator and iPhones.