# iPhone GPS tracking through Gamekit/Bonjour

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps

I'm familiar with CoreLocation, however, I need to design an application that shares the user's location across a shared network for business purposes. I wanted to know what would be the best way to transmit the user's Map Annotation to other devices on the shared network? Is GameKit/Bonjour the best place to start? Thank you for your help! ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you did not provide enough information about your application needs. Anyway, you should read corresponding guides to have an idea about their limitations.

**GameKit**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW18

There are some limitations:

- GameKit is not available for Mac OS X (if you need it too)
- There's maximum number of peers (client-server game is limited to 16 players)

**Bonjour**

FAQ - http://developer.apple.com/networking/bonjour/faq.html

Basically - Bonjour is here to help you identify services on your network. In other words, Bonjour can help you to find other devices with your application on the network, but it doesn't implement data transfer for you. You have to implement it on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far! I suppose I need to rephrase my needs: Both devices will be running the same application. One device needs to track the other's current position and bring it back to the host. I thought of using Bonjour to link them together, but then I'd have to write a packet to encode the GPS data to bring back to the host? Any further guidance you could give would be greatly appreciated! Thanks again! :D

Comment: Yes, you're right - you have send/receive packets on your own. Anyway, there will be just two iOS devices communicating? Is this correct? No other devices, machines, ...

Comment: I think I may have confused myself. The scenario is that the two people using the App will be at two remote locations (miles apart, no wifi), relying on their 3G/4G service to communicate. Is Bonjour still appropriate for this? Or am I better off using REST functionality (ie. sending information from the devices to a server where the receiver will GET the other's information pushed back to their device)?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you did really confuse yourself - you wrote "across shared network" and it looks like it's not truth. Look at this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321222/gamekit-over-the-internet/4321384#4321384 for example to see how you can do this with GameKit.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I'm going to repost this question appropriately. Thank you for your help. :)